# Problema al pasar el parámetro string a js usando el evento onclick y mediante el método createElement mostrarlo en una sección de página web

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Realicé este código para que por medio del evento `onclick` mande un string al *js* para enviar un alert, luego en esta misma función envíe a otra para realizar un contenedor `div` con la función `createElement` y la muestre en una página web diferente, lo malo es que no me muestra dicho contenido y no encuentro solución. Adjunto el código:

**HTML**

```
<th><a class="reserva_dia" href="#" id="btn" onclick="Reserva('101 de 7:00-8:00');" >RS</a></th>
```

---

**JS**

```js
function Reserva(string){
  alert("Se realizó su reserva ");
  crearReserva(string);
}

document.body.onload = crearReserva ()

function crearReserva(string){
    //variables a crear

    //div principal
    const reserva__div = document.createElement ("div");
    //texto
    const textoReservas = document.createTextNode('Reserva en el aula',string);


    //style css 
    reserva__div.classList.add ("contenedorDiv");
      

    //seleccionar a la clase padre
    const cont_reservas = document.querySelector('.cont_reservas');


    //agregar contenido
    cont_reservas.appendChild(reserva__div);
    cont_reservas.appendChild(textoReservas);


}
```

**Captura del resultado**

[image]

Comment: Intenta eliminando el punto y coma del final en tu string de onclick. **Reserva('101 de 7:00-8:00')**

Comment: no funciona bro ya lo probé

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function Reserva(string){
  alert("Se realizó su reserva ");
  crearReserva(string);
}

function crearReserva(string){
     //variables a crear

    //div principal
    const reserva__div = document.createElement ("div");
    //texto
    const textoReservas = document.createTextNode('Reserva en el aula: '+string);


    //style css 
    reserva__div.classList.add ("contenedorDiv");
      

    //seleccionar a la clase padre
    const cont_reservas = document.querySelector(".cont_reservas");


    //agregar contenido
    // va alrevez
    // al div se le asigna el textoNode
    reserva__div.appendChild(textoReservas);
    // y al selector se le asigna el div
    cont_reservas.appendChild(reserva__div);


}

// se comenta porque si no se ejecuta al cargar la pagina
//document.body.onload = crearReserva()
```

```html
<th><a class="reserva_dia" href="#" id="btn" onclick="Reserva('101 de 7:00-8:00')" >RS</a></th>

<div class="cont_reservas">hola</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Prueba esto a ver si te funciona:***

Realiza lo mismo, click al `<a>RS</a>` seguido aparece el alert y cuando sales del alert aparece el div con el string **Reserva en el aula: 101 de 7:00-8:00**

**Crea un solo div:**

```
function Reserva(string){
  alert("Se realizó su reserva ");
  crearReserva(string);
}

function crearReserva(string){
    let divNuevo = document.getElementById("nuevo_div");
    divNuevo.innerHTML = `<div>Reserva en el aula: ${string}</div>`;
}
```

**Crear varios div:**

```
function Reserva(string){
  alert("Se realizó su reserva ");
  crearReserva(string);
}

function crearReserva(string){
    let div = `Reserva en el aula: ${string}`;
    const reserva__div = document.createElement ("div");
    const textoReservas = document.createTextNode(div);

    const cont_reservas = document.querySelector(".cont_reservas");

    reserva__div.appendChild(textoReservas)
    cont_reservas.appendChild(reserva__div);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<th>
   <a id="reserva_dia" onclick="Reserva('101 de 7:00-8:00')">RS</a>
</th>
<div class="cont_reservas"></div>
```